# Simplest way to set image as JPanel background

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jpanel

How would I add the backgroung image to my JPanel without creating a new class or method, but simply by inserting it along with the rest of the JPanel's attributes?

I am trying to set a JPanel's background using an image, however, every example I find seems to suggest extending the panel with its own class.

I have been looking for a way to simply add the image without creating a whole new class and within the same method (trying to keep things organized and simple).

Here is an example of the method that sets my JPanel:

```
public static JPanel drawGamePanel(){
    //Create game panel and attributes
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    Image background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("Background.png");
    gamePanel.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    //Set Return
    return gamePanel;
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem to create custom `JPanel`?

Comment: How would I add the backgroung image to my JPanel without creating a new class or method, but simply by inserting it along with the rest of the JPanel's attributes?

Comment: As I know you can only change color or create like in examples you saw `extends JPanel` :)

Answer (score 30):

> I am trying to set a JPanel's background using an image, however, every example I find seems to suggest extending the panel with its own class

yes you will have to extend `JPanel` and override the `paintcomponent(Graphics g)` function to do so.

```
@Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
}
```

> I have been looking for a way to simply add the image without creating a whole new class and within the same method (***trying to keep things organized and simple***).

You can use other component which allows to add image as icon directly e.g. `JLabel` if you want.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL); 
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(icon);
```

But again in the bracket ***trying to keep things organized and simple*** !! what makes you to think that just creating a new class will lead you to a messy world ?

Answer (score 18):

> Simplest way to set image as JPanel background

Don't use a JPanel. Just use a JLabel with an Icon then you don't need custom code.

See [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for more information as well as a solution that will paint the image on a JPanel with 3 different painting options:

1. scaled
2. tiled
3. actual

Answer (score 5):

As I know the way you can do it is to override `paintComponent` method that demands to inherit `JPanel`

```
 @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // paint the background image and scale it to fill the entire space
    g.drawImage(/*....*/);
}
```

The other way (a bit complicated) to create second custom `JPanel` and put is as background for your main

**ImagePanel**

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image image = null;
private int iWidth2;
private int iHeight2;

public ImagePanel(Image image)
{
    this.image = image;
    this.iWidth2 = image.getWidth(this)/2;
    this.iHeight2 = image.getHeight(this)/2;
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (image != null)
    {
        int x = this.getParent().getWidth()/2 - iWidth2;
        int y = this.getParent().getHeight()/2 - iHeight2;
        g.drawImage(image,x,y,this);
    }
}
}
```

**EmptyPanel**

```
public class EmptyPanel extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public EmptyPanel() {
    super();
    init();
}

@Override
public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
    return false;
}


public void init(){

    LayoutManager overlay = new OverlayLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(overlay);

    ImagePanel iPanel = new ImagePanel(new IconToImage(IconFactory.BG_CENTER).getImage());
    iPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
    this.add(iPanel);
    iPanel.setOpaque(false);                
}
}
```

**IconToImage**

```
public class IconToImage {

Icon icon;
Image image;


public IconToImage(Icon icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
    image = iconToImage();
}

public Image iconToImage() { 
    if (icon instanceof ImageIcon) { 
        return ((ImageIcon)icon).getImage(); 
    } else { 
        int w = icon.getIconWidth(); 
        int h = icon.getIconHeight(); 
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(); 
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice(); 
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration(); 
        BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage(w, h); 
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics(); 
        icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0); 
        g.dispose(); 
        return image; 
    } 
}


/**
 * @return the image
 */
public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the code comment be on the next line?  *"The other way (a bit complicated) to create second custom JPanel and put is as background for your main"*  How does the '2nd panel' actually progress toward a solution?  It seems it comes back to the same basic problem (just in a different panel).

Comment: @AndrewThompson if his main class extends some other class, he can't inherit fromJPanel, therefore he can add new custom JPanel

Answer (score 4):

Draw the image on the background of a JPanel that is added to the frame.  Use a layout manager to normally add your buttons and other components to the panel.  If you add other child panels, perhaps you want to set child.setOpaque(false).

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class BackgroundImageApp {
    private JFrame frame;

    private BackgroundImageApp create() {
        frame = createFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(createContent());

        return this;
    }

    private JFrame createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        return frame;
    }

    private void show() {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Component createContent() {
        final Image image = requestImage();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        for (String label : new String[]{"One", "Dois", "Drei", "Quatro", "Peace"}) {
            JButton button = new JButton(label);
            button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(15, 15)));
            panel.add(button);
        }

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        return panel;
    }

    private Image requestImage() {
        Image image = null;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.johnlennon.com/wp-content/themes/jl/images/home-gallery/2.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new BackgroundImageApp().create().show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Logo extends JPanel
{
    Logo()
    {
        //code
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");
        g.drawImage(img.getImage(), 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

INITIALIZE YOUR JPANEL AS BELOW.  NOTE THE MISSING SEMICOLON.. INSTEAD OPEN A CURLY BRACE THEN OVERRIDE THAT METHOD.. THIS WAY YOU DON'T HAVE TO EXTEND TO ANYTHING

```
  ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("background.jpg");
  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel()
  {
     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
     }
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public demo1() {
    initComponents();
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\AMIT TIWARI\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\try\\src\\com\\dd.jpeg"); //full path of image
    Image img2 = img.getImage().getScaledInstance(mylabel.getWidth(), mylabel.getHeight(),1);
    ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(img2);
    mylabel.setIcon(img3);
}
```