# Java-Graphics-Importing a Background Image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, imageicon

I am messing with java graphics for the first time, after a lot of searching I still can not seem to successfully add in a background, I Have my background image in a seperate file, pre-drawn and i'm trying to import it into my project....
Any help would be VERY appreciated!

```
    public static void startMenu(){
        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("C:/Background.jpg").getImage());

        // Loads the background image and stores in img object
        Window game = new Window();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start"); //makes a button with the text Start
        startButton.setBounds(300, 400, 89, 23);
        startButton.setVisible(true);

        frame.getContentPane().add(startButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // starts it in the center of the
                                            // screen
        frame.setVisible(true);


        game.start(); // Initialize start method
    }
    public static void startButton(){

        }

}


class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

      private Image backgroundImg;

      public ImagePanel(String backgroundImg) {
        this(new ImageIcon(backgroundImg).getImage());
      }

      public ImagePanel(Image backgroundImg) {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(backgroundImg.getWidth(null), backgroundImg.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
      }

    }
```

Comment: This would help [Swing background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125707/simplest-way-to-set-image-as-jpanel-background)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A few things

1. Look at the constructor you're calling:

   ```
   new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("C:/Background.jpg").getImage());
   ```

   Then look at the constructor and `ImagePanel` class

   ```
   class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

       private Image backgroundImg;

       public ImagePanel(Image backgroundImg) {
           Dimension size = new Dimension(
                                backgroundImg.getWidth(null),
                                backgroundImg.getHeight(null));
           ...
       }

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
       }
   }
   ```

   So you're not actually doing anything with the `Image` that you pass to the construtor, besides using its size. You should probably use it to initialize the `backgroundImg`. Like so:

   ```
   private Image backgroundImg;

   public ImagePanel(Image backgroundImg) {
       this.backgroundImg = backgroundImg;
   }
   ```
2. Look at these lines

   ```
   frame.getContentPane().add(startButton);
   frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
   frame.add(game);
   ```

   FYI, `frame.add()` does the same thing as `frame.getContentPane().add()`. And in your case, since you haven't changed the layout of the frame/contentpane, you are left with the default `BorderLayout`. What this means for you is that if you don't specify the position when adding a component, (like `frame.add(component, BorderLayout.PAGE_END)`), then implicitly, you are trying to add to the center, (like `frame.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER)`). Problem with this is that each `BorderLayout` position can only hold one component - the last one you add wins. So in your case `game` wins.

   See [Laying out Components Withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for some other ideas for layout management. Also more directly, see [How to use `BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
3. [`Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) is an AWT component. You shouldn't try and add AWT components to Swing Components. May be better to just use `JPanel` or `JComponent`, though not really sure the purpose of the window
4. `g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);` → `null` should be `this` instead.
5. Get rid of all your `get[Xxx]Size()` in your `ImagePanel` constructor. You don't need them, better to just override `getPreferredSize()`.

   ```
   class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

       private Image backgroundImg;

       public ImagePanel(Image backgroundImg) {
           this.backgroundImg = backgroundImg;
       }

       @Override
       public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
           return new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(this),
                                backgroundImage.getHeight(this));
       }
   }
   ```

   Also have a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)