# How do I add a background image to a JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame and the JPanel is inside it. My game's background is completely black as the entities are on top of it. I would just like to change the background into an image from my computer the "simplest" way without having to change much.

```
public Game() {
    // Frame
    JFrame container = new JFrame("Space Invaders");

    // Resolution
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) container.getContentPane();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    panel.setLayout(null);

    // Canvas Size
    panel.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    panel.add(this);

    // Window Visible
    container.pack();
    container.setResizable(false);
    container.setVisible(true);

    container.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Create a `JLabel`, set it's layout to `BorderLayout`, apply the image to it like you would any other label, set this as the `contentPane` of the frame and continue as you have been. Of course, you could simply use `Graphics#drawImage`, but since I don't know how your code actually works, it's difficult to make a recommendation on what is "simplest"

Comment: Try whats suggested here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125707/simplest-way-to-set-image-as-jpanel-background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You could...

Use a `JLabel` as the background component...

```
JFrame container = new JFrame("Space Invaders");
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...)));
label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
container.setContentPane(label);

// Resolution
// There are simply so many different ways to achieve this
// that are better it's not funny
//JPanel panel = (JPanel) container.getContentPane();
//panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
//panel.setLayout(null);

// Canvas Size
//setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
//panel.add(this);

// Window Visible
container.pack();
container.setResizable(false);
container.setVisible(true);

container.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// Pointless
//container.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
//    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
//          System.exit(0);
//      }
//});
```

The issue with this is:

1. The label will only use the `icon` and `text` property to calculate the `preferredSize` of the label
2. If you're using a `java.awt.Canvas`, then it will paint over this component, as `java.awt.Canvas` can't be transparent.

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details

## You could...

Use `Graphics#drawImage` to draw the background image before you renderer the reset of your content.

This will be, generally, a better solution, as you gain complete control over the size and position of the image and will work if you're using `java.awt.Canvas` and a `BufferStrategy`

See [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) for more details