# Java swing add a component at a given position

Tags: java, swing

I have a picture made by a friend and my job is to insert some java swing components (JLabel, JTextField and JButton)
at first I thought of using `FlowLayout` or `BoxLayout`, but the components aren't aligned
then I thought about using `GridLayout`, but all the components take the same size and don't fit the image anymore
so is there a better way to chose at what pixels should I add my components?

Comment: *"don't fit the image"* Show the image. More generally: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and **if resizable,** with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: Use a custom `JPanel` to [draw the image on its background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125707/simplest-way-to-set-image-as-jpanel-background). Assign a layout manger to the custom `JPanel` and use it as you would use any standard `JPanel`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you'd like to do absolute positioning of your layout. I'm not entirely sure of your usecase, but if you want pixel perfect placement, why not skip using a layout manager and use [Absolute Positioning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) ?