# how to add a background (URL) to a JPanel in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, url, background, imageicon

we just started using java. we want to use an image from the internet and make it the background of our Jpanel. can somebody help us please? we tried using the code below :

```
 public class Achtergrond3 extends JPanel { 
        private ImageIcon img;
        private JLabel label;

        public Achtergrond3() {
             img = new ImageIcon("res/textures/newbackground.jpg"); 
             label= new JLabel(img);

             this.add(label);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link will help you...

[Simplest way to set image as JPanel background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125707/simplest-way-to-set-image-as-jpanel-background)

It talks about how to set image as JPanel background